i am trying to derive the x and y values based on a certain data
here is the events dataframe
events <- data.frame(
  TRTA = c('Xanomeline','Xanomeline', 'Xanomeline', 'Xanomeline', 'Xanomeline', 'Placebo'),
  ASTDY = c(4, 4, 13, 34, 70, 162),
  AEDECOD = c('ABDOMINAL PAIN','ABDOMINAL PAIN', 'ABDOMINAL PAIN', 'ABDOMINAL PAIN', 'ABDOMINAL PAIN', 'ABDOMINAL PAIN'),
  x = c(0, -1.10254, -4.7631, -15.8914, -39.0318, -87.7844),
  y = c(0, 3.8450, 12.0669, 29.8759, 57.4535, 135.4739),
  freq= rep(6,6)
)

I am not sure how to begin with, any thoughts are appreciated.
please help me derive the x and y based on the algorithm from the following article , we need to use TRTA, ASTDY and AEDECOD and freq

steps to follow are
1.Sort the events according to time since randomization.

Calculate the magnitudes of the vectors as the time between subsequent events. For an event occurring at the same time as the
previous event, the magnitude will be zero.

Calculate the angle of the vectors. For each vector the angle is
the cumulative sum of all angles up to that event. The angle is
negative (clockwise rotation) for events on the placebo arm and
positive (counter-clockwise rotation) for events on the active
arm. Zero-magnitude vectors will still contribute to angular
changes. Thus, if 3 events, 2 on placebo and one on active, occur
at the same time, the net effect is a 1 unit clockwise rotation.


4.Add the vectors together cumulatively, i.e., the next vector in
time starts at the end of the previous vector in time. The resulting
sequence of vectors constitutes the tendril for that AE.
Note: From trial-and-error testing and the 1:1 treatment allocation, the tilting angle per event was chosen to be 64 for events on the placebo and roflumilast treatment arm.

Looking through AstraZeneca/Tendril should help with both how to organize your data and functions.
